# Setting up Google Analytics to track multiple snippets?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I made a JS Fiddle to demonstrate this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/8uC4Z/1/

Why does ga.getAll() only have one tracker instead of two? I am following the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced

```
/* https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced */

(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-42441200-1', 'domain1');
ga('send', 'pageview'); // first one created is the default

ga('create', 'UA-35320164-1 ', 'domain2');
ga('domain2.send', 'pageview');

ga(function() {
    console.log("The following is the array of all trackers:");
    console.log(ga.getAll());
    console.log("Why is there only 1 in the array?");
}); // why only 1 snippet?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up on [@Steven V](https://stackoverflow.com/users/254973/steven-v)'s answer...

There can only be one unnamed (default) tracker. When the third parameter is a string:

```
ga('create', 'UA-42441200-1', 'domain1');
```

I'm guessing it's a shortcut for setting the tracker cookieDomain, not the tracker name.

You can use the shortcut code for the first tracker, but have to explictly name the second:

```
ga('create', 'UA-42441200-1', 'domain1');
ga('send', 'pageview'); // first one created is the default
ga('create', 'UA-35320164-1', {'name': 't2'});
ga('t2.send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: The string version was suggested by Google themselves. It's what you get when you go to copy your implementation snippet. I think you are right, and that a third unnamed parameter => cookie domain. I recommend using an object to name the parameters from now on.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced), the correct syntax is:

```
ga('create', 'UA-12345-6', {'name': 'newTracker'});
```

where the third parameter is an object, not a string.

```
ga('create', 'UA-42441200-1', {'name': 'domain1'});
ga('create', 'UA-35320164-1 ', {'name': 'domain2'});
```

works for me with `ga.getAll()` returning two objects.